# tried reverse array but reverse last item instead

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to reverse array items, but it reverse the last item not array. I also posted the expected output. Hope it will make easy to understand.

```js
var color = ("red", "green", "blue");

function printReverse(str) {
  for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(str[i]);
  }
}
printReverse(color);
/*  
  output
  e
  u
  l
  b
  */
```

Comment: Your var color is nor an array, try to put it inside an array : 
 var color = ["red","green","blue"]

Comment: That's not how you initialize an array. Use []

Comment: BTW: arrays have a `reverse` method...

Comment: Thanks, guys. It solved now

Comment: No need to tag as solved. Accepting an answer does the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define arrays with this statement: `["red","green","blue"]`, not this: `("red","green","blue")`:

```js
var color = ["red","green","blue"];
function printReverse(str){
    for ( var i = str.length-1; i>= 0; i-- ){
        console.log(str[i]);
    }
}
printReverse(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = ["red","green","blue"];

var rev_color = color.reverse()
```